# db2 installation failed.Display variable not set properly

Tags: linux, db2

While installing db2 instance on linux after executing ./db2setup command getting following

`error : "The DISPLAY variable is not set properly.  Ensure that the DISPLAY variable is set properly and that permissions are set properly to open windows on the display specified, then rerun the command."`
NOTE : i have connected to RHL VM  through Putty and installing db2 on VM

What could be possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

The DB2 installer wants to open a window on your X server. The solution depends on how you connected to the Linux box (from another Linux box, from Windows, via VNC or SSH, etc.)

Please edit your question to give more details about your setup, specifically what the machine is to which your monitor and keyboard are connected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
The way I solved it:
 1. Install an xserver program (like Micro Focus ViewNow) on your own machine (not the linux VM) 
 2. Turn it on (it will start an xserver)
 3. Figure out your own machine's IP
 4. Log into the linux VM with SSH (like putty)
 5. export DISPLAY=MyIP:0
 6. sudo ./db2setup

Then, the VM will try to open an xterm on your own machine! (should work unless you have a crazy firewall setting).

Answer (score 1):

Hey I had the same problem ....

to solve -
reboot your system and try again ......

Answer (score 0):

The script `./db2setup` starts IBM DB2 GUI installer what is default installation scenario. In that case for Linux/UNIX you need to have GUI Linux system running, or to be more precise, running XServer somewhere.

If you want to install db2 client/server/... using only shell (terminal, ssh, ...) you need to run `./db2_install` script - [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0022615.html):

> Linux and UNIX alternatives - On Linux and UNIX operating systems, an
> alternative installation method provided for database servers is also
> applicable to clients: the db2_install script.